# ajax web app : possible to force bookmarking without url's hash-string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-state

I have a single-page ajax powered web app, however the way my app works is if a hash string is in the url it will load that element which is really useful for people to link to content on it.

When it comes to bookmarking/favouriting things are different. My users want to book mark the app and not the current bit of content (hash string) they're on...

**I'm thinking this is unlikely but is there anyway to get browsers to not include the hash string when the page is bookmarked?**

Comment: How will the users bookmark your page? If you have a bookmarking link on your page then you can use Javascript to polish the URL. If the users use "Ctrl+D" or the like then I don't see how this could be done.

Comment: With a Ajax call the page URL normally doesn't change. What is changing the URL to include the anchor (hash string)?

Comment: basically i'm trying to have my cake AND eat it. I am using the #string to trigger content so that links to content can be shared.
@Satyajit - that's probably the closest i'm going to get. Whats the javascript involved in making a *bookmark this page* button?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with you are using the hash as an anchor, rather than a way to store a page's state in a Ajax application.

There are a few solutions you can implement:

- Don't use anchors (and thus don't use a hash) and thus hash won't be bookmarked. Instead you can use something like jQuery ScrollTo and scroll to the link instead using javascript instead of the built-in anchor support. http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/
- Have a toolbar up the top which contains the url without the hash, or a sidebar.
- Educate your users.

If you are asking about keeping support for anchors in Ajax Web 2.0 Applications, then you may want to look at jQuery Ajaxy as it supports this; as seen by the "Durian" demo: http://www.balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-ajaxy/demo/